Unity 3D movement issue
So i'm trying to create a 3D character movement in unity with state machine, and new input system. I had an issue where the player move faster while strafing, but move for up, down, left, and right are the same. I already normalized the Vector3 moveDir. How can i fix this?
The video link : Unity 3D movement issue
PlayerStateMachine script :
CharacterController playerControl;
PlayerInputSystm playerInput;
PlayerBaseState playerCurrState;
PlayerStateFactory playerCurrFactory;

float xDir;
float zDir;

public CharacterController PlayerControl { get { return playerControl; } }
public PlayerBaseState PlayerCurrState { get { return playerCurrState; } set { playerCurrState = value; } }
public float XDir { get { return xDir; } set { xDir = value; } }
public float ZDir { get { return zDir; } set { zDir = value; } }

private void Awake()
{
    playerControl = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    playerInput = new PlayerInputSystm();
    playerCurrFactory = new PlayerStateFactory(this);
    playerCurrState = playerCurrFactory.Idle();
    playerCurrState.EnterState();
    playerInput.Player.Movement.performed += OnMove;
    playerInput.Player.Movement.canceled += OnMove;
}

void Update()
{
    playerCurrState.UpdateState();
}

void OnMove(InputAction.CallbackContext ctx_move)
{
    xDir = ctx_move.ReadValue<Vector3>().x;
    zDir = ctx_move.ReadValue<Vector3>().z;
}

private void OnEnable()
{
    playerInput.Player.Movement.Enable();
}

private void OnDisable()
{
    playerInput.Player.Movement.Disable();
}

PlayerIdleState script :
public override void UpdateState()
{
    CheckSwitchState();
}
public override void ExitState()
{

}
public override void CheckSwitchState()
{
    if(ctx.XDir != 0 || ctx.ZDir != 0)
    {
        SwitchState(factory.Run());
    }
}

PlayerRunState script :
public override void UpdateState()
{
    CheckSwitchState();
    PlayerMove();
}
public override void ExitState()
{

}
public override void CheckSwitchState()
{
    if(ctx.XDir == 0 || ctx.ZDir == 0)
    {
        SwitchState(factory.Idle());
    }
}

void PlayerMove()
{
    Vector3 moveDir = new Vector3(ctx.XDir, 0, ctx.ZDir).normalized;
    ctx.PlayerControl.Move(moveDir * 3 * Time.deltaTime);
}


Firstly, your event listeners should be in the OnEnable and OnDisable methods, after you have enabled the Player actions. The OnEnable method should look like this
private void OnEnable()
{
    playerInput.Player.Enable();
    
    playerInput.Player.Movement.performed += OnMove;
    playerInput.Player.Movement.canceled += OnMove;
}

And the OnDisable
private void OnDisable()
{
    playerInput.Player.Movement.performed -= OnMove;
    playerInput.Player.Movement.canceled -= OnMove;

    playerInput.Player.Disable();
}

Secondly, your OnMove method should read a Vector2 type, not a Vector3, since as far as I know there's no input device that can give you a Vector3, so your OnMove would look like this
void OnMove(InputAction.CallbackContext ctx_move)
{
    var inputValue = ctx_move.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    xDir = inputValue.x;
    zDir = inputValue.y;
}


Thank you for the feedback, i have done the way you've said, and still the same issue, the player object still move faster while strafing

I have fixed the issue
I updated the update method in the PlayerStateMachine to look like this :
void Update()
    {
        playerCurrState.UpdateState();

        moveDir = new Vector3(xDir, 0, zDir).normalized;
    }

The issue is happened because in my PlayerIdleState script :
if(ctx.XDir != 0 || ctx.ZDir !=0){
  SwitchState(factory.Run());
}

Is reading two input at once. So i modified it like this :
if (ctx.MoveDir != Vector3.zero)
        {
            SwitchState(factory.Run());
        }

And then in the PlayerRunState script i modified it like this :
public override void UpdateState()
    {
        CheckSwitchState();
        PlayerMove();
    }
    public override void CheckSwitchState()
    {
        if(ctx.MoveDir == Vector3.zero)
        {
            SwitchState(factory.Idle());
        }
    }

void PlayerMove()
    {
        ctx.PlayerControl.Move(ctx.MoveDir * 3 * Time.deltaTime);
    }


And now the player move at the same speed at any direction
